# Why is my toString() method not printing my LinkedList in the command prompt?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a singly-linked-list with head and tail references. In order to test my script, I created a toString() method that would be able to print out each node in the list. However, it appears that I am entering an infinite loop every time I call the method and I cannot seem to figure out why. Would anyone be able to give me some insight on this? See below for my SinglyLinkedList.java file.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Your implementation of a Singly-Linked List.
 */
public class SinglyLinkedList<T> {
    
    /*
     * Do not add new instance variables or modify existing ones.
     */
    private SinglyLinkedListNode<T> head;
        private SinglyLinkedListNode<T> tail;
        private int size;
    
    /*
     * Do not add a constructor.
     */

    /**
     * Adds the element to the front of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(1) time.
     *
     * @param data the data to add to the front of the list
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if data is null
     */
        public void addToFront(T data) {
        if (data == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null");
        }
            SinglyLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data);
        if (head == null){
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        newNode.setNext(head);
        head = newNode;
        size++;
        }

    /**
     * Adds the element to the back of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(1) time.
     *
     * @param data the data to add to the back of the list
     * @throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException if data is null
     */
    public void addToBack(T data) {
        if (data == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null");
        }
            if (head == null){
            head = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data);
        }
        else {
            SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
            while (current.getNext() != null){
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            current.setNext(new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data));
        }
        size++;
        }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the first data of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(1) time.
     *
     * @return the data formerly located at the front of the list
     * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if the list is empty
     */
        public T removeFromFront() {
        if (head == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("You cannot remove elements from the front of an empty list");
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> var = head;
            head = head.getNext();
        size--; 
        return var.getData();
        }

    /**
     * Removes and returns the last data of the list.
     *
     * Method should run in O(n) time.
     *
     * @return the data formerly located at the back of the list
     * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if the list is empty
     */
        public T removeFromBack() {
            if (head == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("You cannot remove an element from the back of an empty list");
        }
        else if (head.getNext() == null){
            SinglyLinkedListNode<T> var = head;
            head = null;
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
        while (current.getNext().getNext() != null){
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> var = current.getNext();
        current.setNext(null);
        size--;
        return var.getData();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the head node of the list.
     *
     * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
     * you have direct access to the variable.
     *
     * @return the node at the head of the list
     */
        public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> getHead() {
        // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
            return head;
        }

    /**
     * Returns the tail node of the list.
     *
     * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
     * you have direct access to the variable.
     *
     * @return the node at the tail of the list
     */
        public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> getTail() {
        // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
            return tail;
        }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the list.
     *
     * For grading purposes only. You shouldn't need to use this method since
     * you have direct access to the variable.
     *
     * @return the size of the list
     */
        public int size() {
        // DO NOT MODIFY THIS METHOD!
            return size;
        }
    
    public String toString() {
        String answer = "";
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> current = head;
        while (current != null){
            answer += current + "";
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SinglyLinkedList<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
        list.addToFront(1);
        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```

And here is my SinglyLinkedListNode.java file.

```
/**
 * Node class used for implementing the SinglyLinkedList.
 *
 * DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE!!
 *
public class SinglyLinkedListNode<T> {

        private T data;
        private SinglyLinkedListNode<T> next;

    /**
     * Constructs a new SinglyLinkedListNode with the given data and next node
     * reference.
     *
     * @param data the data stored in the new node
     * @param next the next node in the list
     */
        SinglyLinkedListNode(T data, SinglyLinkedListNode<T> next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }

    /**
     * Creates a new SinglyLinkedListNode with only the given data.
     *
     * @param data the data stored in the new node
     */
        SinglyLinkedListNode(T data) {
            this(data, null);
        }

    /**
     * Gets the data.
     *
     * @return the data
     */
        T getData() {
            return data;
        }

    /**
     * Gets the next node.
     *
     * @return the next node
     */
        SinglyLinkedListNode<T> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

    /**
     * Sets the next node.
     *
     * @param next the new next node
     */
        void setNext(SinglyLinkedListNode<T> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are various errors in your code; this question is specifically about why your toString seems to 'hang' so I'll answer just that one here. But, just to give an example, your toString just "prints" `current`, which is an object, hence, short for `current.toString()`, but SLLN has no toString method and thus isn't going to produce useful information. You presumably want `current.getData().toString()` instead.

It has nothing in particular to do with your `toString` method. It's your addToFront method that is broken in a way that causes endless loops.

Learn to debug. It's easy! You think up some example input, then you 'run the code in your head' - you go through your code line by line and you become the computer: Get a scratch pad out if you have to, but write down every change to every variable, every effect. Then, use a debugger, or if you don't want to learn how to use one right now, you can fake it by adding a ton of `System.out.println` statements that print the values of various expressions/variables, and compare what you think ought to happen with what actually happens. Every time you find a disagreement: You found a bug.

For example, imagine that your SinglyLinkedList is **empty**, and then add an element to it by invoking `addToFront`:

> ```
> if (data == null){
>            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data cannot be null");
>        }
> ```

It's not `null` so this part does what we'd expect: 'hop over' the if block, nothing happens here. You could debug this by simply witnessing the IAEx is not occurring.

> ```
>   SinglyLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data);
>   if (head == null){
>       head = newNode;
>       tail = newNode;
>   }
> ```

This is a brand new list so that `if` block should be entered. If you're not 100% certain you should add some sysout statements in there so that you know this happens. Point is, `head` and `tail` and `newNode` are now all variables that are all pointing at the exact same object - that one node you just made to represent the data being added.

> ```
> newNode.setNext(head);
> head = newNode;
> size++;
> ```

Perhaps you missed this, but, this code will run too! Why wouldn't it?

`newNode` is pointing at the object you just made. So is `head`. So now you're telling your new node that its next node is.. itself. Which means that any attempt to traverse this node will **be infinite** - it's just a thing that points to itself. Perhaps you intended this part to be in an `else` block.

An alterate route to debug this is to debug the toString process. Use a debugger, or add some sysout statements to toString itself (a tad dangerous, make sure you just print strings and primitives - or you may end up with infinite recursion; at least that will cause a StackOverflowError that'll give away what is happening, though) - and you'd have noticed that it keeps calling itself over and over again. Then use some common sense which should lead you to the conclusion that a node must be pointing at itself or otherwise there is now a 'loop' in the node's `.next` chain, and from there you'd get back to figuring it out, or at least you'd know to look at `addToFront` once you've drawn that conclusion.

This never goes away - expert programmers just become better at the process and can intuit more. In other words, getting experienced at debugging is, pretty much by definition, a significant and requisite step in becoming a programmer.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful feedback! Debugging is certainly a challenge as I typically write my script in notepad rather than using a more advanced IDE with debugging capabilities. However, I added an else statement to my addToFront() method and it appears to have stopped the endless loop! I am still however a bit confused with my toString() method. It seems to keep printing out the object "current" rather than the list in a string format. Where are you suggesting I add current.getData().toString() in my script? I would like to see all the numbers in my list as shown in my main method.

Comment: I suggested it _just to debug_ in the crappy way (with sysout statements instead of a debugger).

Comment: Would you happen to know the reason why my toString() method is outputting the object rather than the linked list in a string format? I would like to view the entire linked-list after I call upon different operations to see if they are operating correctly?

Comment: I explained it in this answer: Because your Node object (the one you can't change) doesn't have a toString method. Print the result of invoking .getData() on it.

Answer (score 0):

From your `addToFront()` method:

> ```
> [...]
> SinglyLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data);
> if (head == null){
>     head = newNode;
>     tail = newNode;
> }
> newNode.setNext(head);
> [...]
> ```

When you start with a fresh linked list and add the first element ever with this method, you will create a new node `newNode`, which you save in `this.head` and `this.tail`. However, you also change the `next` field in the  new created `SinglyLinkedListNode<T>` instance to `head` via the `newNode.setNext(head);` method call. This will set the `next` field of the `newNode` instance to the `newNode` instance itself, creating a loop.

Maybe you want to do something like `if-else` to check if it is a new list or an existing list like this:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>(data);
if (head == null){
    head = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
} else {
    newNode.setNext(head);
    head = newNode;
}
```